# list won't change values for pygame rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to recreate snake in pygame for fun but the list won't update for the rectangle positions, anyone know what I'm doing wrong with this code???

I passed in a list within a list (snake_body) to a function with this code however the list within a list doesn't change its integer values

```
if event.key == pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_w:
    snake_body[0][1] -= 50

if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or pygame.K_s:
    snake_body[0][1] += 50

if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or pygame.K_d:
    snake_body[0][0] += 50

if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_a:
    snake_body[0][0] -= 50

    print(snake_body)

>>> [[370, 50, 30, 30]]
```

but the up output should be
>>> [[320, 50, 30, 30]]

anything would be helpful as I have been stuck on this for a day and it is no longer fun.

Comment: There's not enough here for us to tell what is wrong. What happens when you run your code.. do the if statements get triggered?  Is snake_body being printed? Do you get any errors? What is [[int, int, int, int]]? Why do you have a list of types?

Comment: might wanna take a look at how to ask a good question: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and more specifically [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe it can be useful to give us a real sample of the list and what you expect as the code's output.

Answer (score 2):

See [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value). A condition like

> ```py
> if event.key == pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_w:
> ```

does not do what you expect. It always evaluates to `True`. The correct syntax is:

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
```